# In Spring Data Jpa, how can I run an SQL union query from two different datasources...?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need to perform a SQL join of two entities and with different data sources. I have an entity A with datasource A and an entity B with datasource B, and I need to do something like this ...

```
"select new A(a,b) from A a, B b where a.id = b.id"
```

I'm using two databases and I have two datasources configuration, one for each

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware like mycat2 to do this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).